# Previous Ruby on Rails application in Cloud9 running on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and working through some tutorials, using Cloud9 as an IDE. I recently switched to making a second app only to find that the first one runs on the server available for preview. I have tried starting the new app with $ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT. I have tried stopping the server on the first app with Ctrl + C in the command box. None of this is doing anything. The first application is the only one that displays.

Can someone please explain what is going on? How do I associate the base URL in Preview with the one set in the routing of my new application and why isn't this being done automatically?

Comment: Did you create a new workspace for your second project?

Comment: Is that necessary? You can't have multiple projects per workspace?

Comment: If they're two independent projects, it's better to have separate workspaces established. Or, maybe you can get away with it if both projects are isolated from each other in your workspace. For example, workspace/project1 and workspace/project2. This would be equivalent to having two separate rails projects in one directory.

Comment: +1 on @iamjhu comment. Can you share a screenshot of how you've arranged your projects within the workspace?

Comment: @Mutahhir, just submitted a guide below that I think will help the OP achieve the results he's looking for. I tested it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think the following will work on C9. But personally, I still think separate workspaces would work best.

Create a new project in C9, this will create a new workspace for you. While the folder tree will display the name of your project, the terminal will display `~/workspace`. The two are synonymous (for now). This will be your first rails project.

To create a second project within the same C9 space, do the following:

1. In terminal, `cd ..` to go up one level. This should take you to the root `~` directory.
2. Type `rails new <name-of-second-project>` to create a new project.
3. At the top of the folder tree, click on the gear wheel. Unselect *Show Root File System* and Select *Show Home in Favorites*.

[image: screenshot of changing folder tree settings]

4. If you look at your folder tree now, you should see both of your rails projects. The first is listed as `workspace` and the second is whatever you named your second project.

[image: screenshot of results from updating folder tree settings]

5. If you want to rename `workspace` to match the actual name of your project, `mv workspace <name-of-first-project>`.

[image: screenshot of renaming workspace project]

That's pretty much it. You can now navigate into each folder and treat it as a separate rails project. When using `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT` in the terminal, just make sure you're in the correct directory, depending on which project you want to run the server for and it'll work.